# Remove SQL Server 2012 db_denydatareader schema from a user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I accidentally made a SQL Server user own the `db_denydatareader` schema. I understand that normally to remove this ownership you need to transfer it to another user.

But I don't want to transfer a "deny" schema to another user. Also I understand you can create a bogus user and transfer it but then you can't delete that user once it owns the schema right?

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Just use the same statement , only replace `grant` with `deny` , or you can do that with **ssms**

Comment: I'd transfer ownership to the dbo user.

Comment: By default db_denydatareader and db_datareader schemas are not owned by anyone. So once that check box is checked, it must be owned by someone and can only be transferred? And transferring db_denydatareader to DBO will not limit or change any permissions to what DBO has access to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i just figured it out. The schema by default owns itself. so you can just go to properties of the schema and put the schema owner back to itself.

Comment: This solution solved it for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48749465/master-user-lost-its-permissions-unexpectedly-on-sql-server-rds-instance/48755710#48755710